# Which closed subsets $Y$ of a compact space $X$ admit a linear extensor $C(Y)\to C(X)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, operator-theory, compactness

In the following $X$ is a Hausdorff compact topological space. Let $Y$ be a closed subset of $X$.
The restriction operator $R_Y:C(X)\to C(Y)$ is surjective (Tietze), so it admits a continuous right inverse (by Bartle-Graves Selection Theorem) but it may fail to have a *bounded linear* right inverse (an "extension operator"). Equivalently, $\text{ker}R_Y=\{f\in C(X): f_{|Y}=0\}$ may fail to be complemented in $C(X)$.

The possibly simpler counterexample is mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392394/nonseparable-counterexamples-in-analysis/392406#392406), with $X:=\beta\mathbb N$ and $Y:=\beta\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$.

Notably, here the closed set $Y$ is not metrisable. In fact ([Lutzer and Martin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2040623), 1974)
a metrisable $G_\delta$ subset $Y$ of $X$ does admit  an extension operator --this generalises the classical Borsuk-Dugundji theorem, where $X$ is a metric space.

Metrisability of $Y$ is certainly not necessary, in general (e.g. in the quite trivial case of a clopen subset $Y$). Being a $G_\delta$ subset, that is, the zero set of a continuous function on $X$, is also not necessary, in general (e.g. in the quite trivial case of $Y=\{x_0\}$, where $x_0\in\ X$ does not have a countable basis of neighborhoods).

> **Question 1.** Can we weaken the metrisability condition from Lutzer-Martin theorem, that is, what more general conditions on a closed set $Y$ ensure the existence of an extension operator?

The reason why in the above example with $X:=\beta\mathbb N$ and $Y:=\beta\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N$ the restriction operator $C(X)\to C(Y)$ is not a left-inverse is that $C(X)\sim\ell_\infty$ has a $w^*$-separable dual, whereas $C(Y)\sim \ell_\infty/c_0$ has not. This seems quite difficult to translate into more direct topological properties of $(X,Y)$. So it may be difficult to find a topological condition that guarantees the existence of an extension operator.

> **Question 2.** Given a nbd $U$ of a closed set $Y$, can we find a closed set $Y'$ that admits an extension operator, $Y\subset Y'\subset U$?

**Question 3.** Suppose $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ admits an extension operator. Does $Y_1\cap Y_2$ admit an extension operator too?

**Rmk.** An extension operator $E:C(Y)\to C(X)$ is always of the form $Ef(x)= \langle Px,f\rangle$, where $P:X\to C(Y)^*$ is continuous w.r.to the $w^*$ topology of $C(Y)^*$ and $Py=\delta_y$ for all $y\in Y$.

Comment: There are some errors in your second paragraph (*Lutzer* is misspelt, the word 'closed' in omitted in one place, and $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\})$ is $G_\delta$ in $\beta\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Thank you (I've deleted some silly stuff added at the last moment!).

Comment: You might also have a look at [Simultaneous linear extension of continuous functions](https://doi.org/10.1016/0016-660X(75)90002-1) by Eric van Douwen

Comment: Some thoughts. $(1)$ As observed by Borges, if $X$ is collectionwise normal and $A\subseteq X$ is closed with metrisable boundary, then $A$ admits a continuous linear extender. $(ii)$ By Heath-Lutzer, If $X$ is a compact GO space and $A\subseteq X$ is closed, then $A$ admits a continuous linear extender. $(iii)$ If $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $A\subseteq X$ is a closed subset with Souslin number exceeding the density of $X$, then $A$ admits no continuous linear extender (this is a topological explanation of why $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}\subseteq\beta\mathbb{N}$ admits no extender).

Comment: Thank you, all very interesting. You may make it into an answer if you wish. Btw, I'm not familiar with the term "collectionwise normal". What is the difference wrto just "normal", could you give me a link to the definition?

Comment: I'll try to find time later on to write something up with references. A space is collectionwise normal if every discrete family of its closed sets has a discrete open expansion. Think of the separation property for pairs of closed sets in a normal space, but for arbitrary families. Every paracompact $T_2$ space is collectionwise normal, and every collectionwise normal space is normal.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment expanding on the remarks I left in the comments. It's far from a definitive answer. To make the discussion less technical, I'll restrict to compact Hausdorff spaces so that there is no distinction between bounded and unbounded functions. Continuity of functions regarding $C(X)$ will always refer to the norm topology (and I hope I got these aspects correct).

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $A\subseteq X$ a closed subspace. Then the pair $(X,A)$ admits both a linear extender and a continuous extender. It may fail to admit a continuous linear extender.

To produce a linear extender $C(A)\rightarrow C(X)$ it suffices to define it on the members of a linear basis of $C(A)$. Due to the Tietze Extension Theorem, this can always be done. The result is almost never continuous. On the other hand, continuous, nonlinear  extenders have been produced by Lutzer and Przymusiński [5].

Now, here is a positive result which slightly weakens the metrisability condition. It's an old observation due to Carlos Borges.

> **Theorem (Borges)** Let $X$ be compact Hausdorff. Then for any closed subspace $A\subseteq X$ which has metrisable boundary, the pair $(X,A)$ admits a continuous linear extender.

The trick is to use the assumption to produce an extender $\gamma:C(\partial A)\rightarrow C(X\setminus A^\circ)$ and then define $\psi:C(A)\rightarrow C(X)$ by
$$\psi(f)(x)=\begin{cases}\gamma(f|_{\partial A})(x)&x\in X\setminus A^\circ\\f(x)&x\in A^\circ.\end{cases}$$

I'll refer to Borges's paper [1] for the details, where the assumption that $A$ is a zero set in $X$ is not used.

There is a class of spaces in which continuous linear extenders always exist. These are the generalised ordered spaces.

> **Theorem (Heath, Lutzer [3])** If $X$ is a compact GO space, then a continuous linear extender exists for any closed subspace.

Finding a complete characterisation of those spaces $X$ for which every closed subset $A\subseteq X$ admits a continuous linear extender is difficult. Clearly such a space must be normal. van Douwen in the paper [2] linked by KP Hart in the comments showed that if the operator norms of the extenders are required to be suitably uniformly bounded, then $X$ must even be hereditarily collectionwise normal.

While every compact Hausdorff space is normal, they are generally not hereditarily so. Still, van Douwen does produce in [2] an example of a basically disconnected compact Hausdorff space admitting continuous linear extenders for each closed subspace, which does fail to be hereditarily collectionwise normal.

A few no-go results appear in the literature. One of the most useful is as follows.

> **Proposition** If $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $A\subseteq X$ is a closed subspace with $c(A)>d(X)$, then the pair $(X,A)$ admits no continuous linear extender.

This is proved, for instance in the survey paper [4]. Here $c(A)$ is the cellularity, or Souslin number, of $A$, defined to be the supremum of all cardinalities of pairwise-disjoint families of open sets of $A$. The density $d(X)$ is the least cardinality of any dense subset of $X$.

Since $c(\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N})=2^{\aleph_0}$, we obtain a topological explanation for the following.

> **Corollary** The pair $(\beta\mathbb{N},\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N})$ admits no continuous linear extender.

Finally, I want to ask if extenders exist for monotonically normal compacta. Monotone normality is one of the strongest normality properties. It's hereditary, and it implies both collectionwise normality and countable paracompactness. Every GO space is monotonically normal, and there is the result of Mary Ellen Rudin that the monotonically normal compacta are exactly the images of compact linearly ordered spaces.

It's known that every monotonically normal space admits *monotone* extenders for each closed subspace. On the other hand, there are examples of monotonically normal spaces which do not admit continuous linear extenders for their closed subspaces. I don't know of any *compact* examples appearing in the literature.

> **Question** Is there a monotonically normal compactum $X$ and a closed a closed subspace $A\subseteq X$ without a continuous linear extender?

*Edit*: Thanks to KP Hart for a correction in the comments.

**References**

[1] C. Borges, *Another Generalization of the Dugundji Extension Theorem*, Colloquium Mathematicae **56** (2) 2 (1988), 263-265.

[2] E. van Douwen, *Simultaneous linear extension of Continuous functions*, Gen. Top. and App. **5** (4) 4 (1975), 297-319.

[3] R. Heath, D. Lutzer, *Dugundji Extension Theorems for Linearly Ordered Spaces*, Pacific J. Math. **55** (1974), 419-425.

[4] D. Lutzer, *A survey of Dugundji Extension Theory*, Seminar Uniform Spaces (1978), 24-42.

[5] D. Lutzer, T. Przymusiński, *Continuous Extenders in Normal and Collectionwise Normal Spaces*, Fundamenta Math. **102** (1979), 165-171.

Comment: Thank you for the  detailed answer! The existence of a continuous extender is in fact a consequence of Tietze (the restriction operator $C(X)\to C(Y)$  being surjective),  because every surjective bounded linear operator between Banach space, admits a continuous right inverse  (in general nonlinear, nor differentiable) .

Comment: In fact what I’m mostly interested is when X is a compact Hausdorff space with no other assumptions: what can be said on the family of its closed subsets A for which there exists a linear bounded extender? (e.g. question 2, and question 3 , added now).

On the Corollary: so it gives another proof of $c_0$ not being complemented in $\ell_\infty$, ritgth?

Comment: The cellularity of $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$ rather than $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @KPHart.